# How to understand which user cucumber tests are referring to when writing in the first person?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, bdd

I'm trying to write my current applications cucumber features in the first person, for example:

```
Given I am logged in as a user
And Mark is a user
When I send him a friend request
Then he should have a friend request from me
And he should receive an email
```

I'm struggling to properly write the steps to make sure I'm referencing the right user with 'him', 'he' and 'me'.

I could handle:

```
When I send Mark a friend request
```

By using:

```
When /^I send (.+) a friend request$/ do |user|
  @user = User.find_by_email(user.downcase + "@test.org")
  visit '/users/' + @user.id.to_s
  click_button "Add Friend"
end
```

But would much rather be able to use 'him' or 'he'.

I'm thinking to achieve that I should really be assigning @second_user or some other variable in the step '(.+) is a user'.

Is that correct?

Any advice on this greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I think this will end up being more trouble than it's worth.  Sitting here trying to come up with a solution, I can't think of anything that wouldn't end up becoming a burden eventually, in the case of re-using those step definitions in future scenarios, or even the mental tax for future readers trying to figure out the flow of execution.

I actually *prefer* the explicitness of using the name at every step rather than the pronoun.  In my experience, especially when interactions between entities become more complex, it's actually really helpful to refer to 'Alice' and 'Bob' instead of 'him' and 'me' or 'User1' and 'User2', in order to follow what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I quite liked the idea of writing the tests in the first person, and then it felt more natural for them to refer to the initial user by name at setup, and then he/her him/she from then on, but that, as you say, it seemed to get increasingly complex when I actually started building it.  I'll keep playing and come back here with my solution - but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch Mark at the second step:

```
And Mark is a user
```

This step must be verified, i.e. Mark must exist. Then you can refer him in third step.

How about in Features:

```
Given I am logged in as a user
And A user exists with name "Mark"
When I send him a friend request
```

Then in `user_steps.rb`

```
Given /^I am logged in as a user$/ do
    pending #blah blah
end

Given /^A user exists with name "([^"]+)"$/ |username| do
    @user = User.find_by_email(username.downcase + "@test.org")
    @user.should be_true
end

When /^I send (\w+) a friend request$/ do |user|
    user = @user
    # visit blah blah
end
```

Comment: I catch 'I' as user in the first step, so I'll play with catching 'Mark' as user_2 and verifying it (thanks for the tip).Then on the When (3rd) step, I think I want to check whether the string is 'he|him|she|her' and reference user_2.

Comment: @idrysdale, yes "I" is the first user to catch, you can use "sender" and "receiver" as var name which sounds nature. For step 3, I think your regex is okay. It's also okay to use him/her as the user variable in step3 always comes from an existing user defined elsewhere.